# Why my web site can't be reached using my domain address?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, domain

I have created a DNS server using following files, to map my domain address `sudia.com` into my VPS server, but it doesn't work and I can't reach to my server using my domain address.  also must say there is an NginX running on `ttp://136.243.197.164:3200`.

/etc/named.conf:
directory       "/var/named";
dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
allow-query     { localhost; 136.243.197.164;};

```
        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

//forward zone
zone "sudia.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "fwd.sudia.com.db";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};

//backward zone
zone "197.243.136.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "sudia.com.rev";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};
```

/var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. root.sudia.com. (
                                              3           ;Serial
                                              3600        ;Refresh
                                              1800        ;Retry
                                              604800      ;Expire
                                              86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sudia.com.

;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       136.243.197.164

;A - Record HostName To Ip Address
www     IN  A       136.243.197.164

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sudsuz.com.
```

/var/named/sudia.com.rev:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. root.itzgeek.local. (
                                       3           ;Serial
                                       3600        ;Refresh
                                       1800        ;Retry
                                       604800      ;Expire
                                       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@         IN      NS         ns1.sudia.com.

;Reverse lookup for Name Server
164        IN  PTR     ns1.sudia.com.

;PTR Record IP address to HostName
164      IN  PTR     www.sudia.com
```

EDIT: This is the result of `host www.sudia.com`:

```
www.sudia.com has address 136.243.197.164
```

But `host sudia.com` (without `www`) doesn't work!

Comment: So, when your name server is running, what does "host www.sudsaz.com" give you?   Please add the answer to your question.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: I added the result in edit part.

Comment: `www.sudsaz.com refused to connect` - That's a web server problem, not a DNS problem.

Comment: `The domain literal has no address records`

Comment: @joeqwerty: In which file you mean? How should I add it?

Comment: That's `@ IN A 136.243.197.164`. But where's your secondary authoritative name server? And did you notice that typo in your `ftp IN CNAME`?

Comment: Do you have a webserver listening on port 80?  If not, you will have to connect to www.sudsaz.com:3200 (or any other port on which a webserver is listening and which your firewall lets through).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zone-file donsen't has the correct record for [www.sudia.com](http://www.sudia.com). Add this to your zone. E.g. by changing this file `/var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db` or via nsupdate:

Method 1 (Update file `/var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db`, don't forget to update serial):

```
@    IN    A    136.243.197.164
```

Method 2 (nsupdate) e.g.:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# nsupdate -k /etc/rndc.key
> server localhost
> zone sudia.com.
> update add sudia.com. 3600 IN A 136.243.197.164
> send
[root@ns1 ~]#
```

Then your nameserver can solve the root-domain e.g. sudia.com to the correct ip address.

Comment: I did what you said but got this result: 
`; TSIG error with server: tsig indicates error
update failed: NOTAUTH(BADKEY)`